# Getting Yum/RPM version of a pip package (django-tables2)

Tags: pip, rpm, yum, django-tables2

I need to use a python package on a CentOS7 machine at work.  I can't use pip which is the only installation method specified by the package (django-tables2).

I can think of three possible solutions:

1. find via YUM
2. convert whl file to rpm
3. build from source

I can't seem to locate the package in yum, but maybe someone more proficient with yum repositories knows how to find it.  I know how to list files in my current repos but have no idea how to explore other repos.

I've looked at trying to convert the whl file but have found nothing and suspect it's just not a thing.

So are there any good options besides the headache of building from source?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-rpm-packages

Comment: https://jeromebelleman.gitlab.io/posts/devops/setuppy/

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyp2rpm/

Comment: https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/python.html